# Cannot compile project after adding library

Tags: android

I have added today a library ( almost the same from gith but from a developer Branch where there are few things changed and I wanted to use both libraries )

After fixing everything I have tryed to run my project and I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

my gradle files are:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.marian.digimusicstream"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile("org.restlet.jse:org.restlet.ext.httpclient:2.1.2") {
        exclude group: 'org.restlet', module: 'jse'
        exclude group: 'org.restlet.ext', module: 'ss1'
    }

    android {
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
            exclude 'META-INF/services/org.restlet.engine.ClientHelper'
        }
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'net.koofr:java-koofr:1.2.8'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5'
    compile 'org.restlet.jse:org.restlet.ext.jackson:2.1.2'
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.android-process-button:library:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:1.8.3'
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.+@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile project(':..:ExoPlayer:library')
    compile project(':..:ExoPlayerdev:libraryDev')
}
```

Untill now I was use library but today I added libraryDev

and in settings:

```
include ':app', ':..:ExoPlayer:library', ':..:ExoPlayerdev:libraryDev'
```

I add libraries from other projects from android studio, untill now I runned ExoPlayer in android studio but exoPlayerdev didn't that may be the problem ?

Comment: Happens on and off for me. I have reinstalled studio, the jdk, and created a new project. each fixed it for awhile but it comes back. a permanent fix would be nice. Note that rebuilding the project should fix it temporarily